# Hierarchical Transformation: define transformation level as anything greater than zero?

Tags: kentico

When you are defining a transformation used within a hierarchical transformation you can enter -1 to mean all, or an integer for a level.

I see that the transformations apply following an order of operations where explicitly defined levels supersede -1 (All).

In my case, I want to apply a transformation to everything except for root level items for a document type.

The only way I have figured out to make this work is to create a transformation for -1 (all) and then create a transformation for level 1. inside of this transformation, I don't do anything (but I had to enter something into the the transformation so I just put an HTML comment).

This seems like a bit of an ugly hack -- is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is similar - But to create a standard "`EmptyHerarchicalTransformation`" control that can be referenced anywhere I need to stop the higher-up hierarchy transformation overriding it.